# How to get the childSelector in the jquery on() function

Tags: jquery

I add dynamically list elements (html li) with Jquery and try to create a function to remove it : here is my html code:

```
<ul id="tags_liste" class="list-inline">
  <li class="tags">
    <a href="" title="">
      <span class="label label-primary">Tag 1</span>
    </a>  
    <a href="" title="Delete this tag" class="form_ajout_tag_suppr">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tags">
    <a href="" title="">
      <span class="label label-primary">Tag 2</span>
    </a>
    <a href="" title="Deletethis tag" class="form_ajout_tag_suppr">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and my Jquery code:

```
$("#tags_liste").on("click", ".form_ajout_tag_suppr", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var sThis = $(this).attr("id");

  console.log("sThis : " + sThis);

  if (confirm("Do you really want to delete this tag?")) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "../../bobookmarks/content/json/delete_tag_in_session.php",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        sLibelle: sTag
      },
      success: function(data, statut) {
        if (data == "ok") {
          $(this).parent().remove();
        } else {

          return false;
        }
      },
      error: function(resultat, statut, erreur) {
        var s = "An error has occured";
        console.log(s);
      },
    })
  }
});
```

The `sThis` variable is null because there is no id of course, so I want to would like to get which li element is clicked to remove it with the code `$this.parent().remove()` in the $.ajax success block.

Maybe I do not use the right way for the jquery on() function.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Where do you use `sThis`, I can see an `sTag` but no `sThis` (after you've assigned the variable, except for the `console.log()`); also: why do you need the `id`, you already have a reference to the clicked element in `this` (DOM) and `$(this)` (jQuery object)? From the clicked element, to get to the ancestor `<li>`, just use `this.closest('li')` (DOM, in compliant browsers) or `$(this).closest('li')` (jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

remove the `attr('id')` and just use the jQuery object.

```js
$("#tags_liste").on("click", ".form_ajout_tag_suppr", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var sThis = $(this);

  if (confirm("Do you really want to delete this tag?")) {
    $.ajax({
      ...
      data: {
        sLibelle: sTag
      },
      success: function(data, statut) {
        if (data == "ok") {

          sThis.parent().remove();

        } else {

          return false;
        }
      },
      error: function(resultat, statut, erreur) {
        var s = "An error has occured ";
        console.log(s);
      },
    })
  }
});
```